# How to do MATH with DERIVATIVE(mean("Field1"-"Field2"),1h).... ERROR: expected field argument in mean()

Tags: influxdb, derivative, influxql

Trying to use a calculated field with derivative

```
 DERIVATIVE(mean("Field1"-"Field2"),1h)
```

results in InfluxDB Error: expected field argument in mean(), so I tried

```
DERIVATIVE(mean("Field1"-"Field2" AS "Field3"),1h)
```

but that creates a parsing error: Found AS, expected )

DERIVATIVE works fine with a single field I just cant get it to work with a bit of MATH between two fields. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no easy way to do match btw multiple fields in InfluxQL.

You might try Flux.

Quick sample code is:

```
from(bucket: "example-bucket")
    |> range(start: -1m)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "A" or r._field == "B")
    |> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: r.A - r.B}))
    |> derivative(nonNegative: true)
```

See more details below.

[First is to calculate the mean btw two fields:](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/common-queries/multiple-fields-in-calculations/)

1. Filter by the two fields required in your calculation
2. Pivot the two fields into two columns
3. Perform the mathematic calculation

The resulted Flux will be:

```
from(bucket: "example-bucket")
    |> range(start: -1m)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "A" or r._field == "B")
    |> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: r.A - r.B}))
```

[Second is to calculate the derivate:](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/derivative/)

The resulted Flux will be:

```
sampledata.int()
    |> derivative(nonNegative: true)
```

Comment: thanks, I'm just moving over to flux from ql so can't confirm as yet